# how to write a password in a textbox with *** in c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to make an windows application and for sing in part i have an username and a password. I want to know how to write a password without showing it, i mean to show *** instead of characters in the password.

Comment: Apart from `PasswordChar`, for a standard • display, you can set [`UseSystemPasswordChar = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.usesystempasswordchar(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `PasswordChar`:

```
passwordtextbox.PasswordChar = '*';
```